# Этимология слова "заядлый"

Tags: этимология

А вот интересно, какое происхождение у слова "заядлый" (то есть, большой любитель чего-то, опытный в чем-то человек)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте уточним смысл слова *заядлый*. Им обычно характеризуют человека, пристрастившегося к какому-либо занятию, и которого неудержимо к нему тянет. Вкушать прелести любимого занятия - вот главная задача заядлого любителя оперы, рыбалки, выпивки, чтения, картежной игры, розыгрышей, лыжных прогулок и других развлечений. Ключевое здесь слово - *вкус*, а понятие вкуса первым делом связано у нас с едой.

Корень *яд (ед)* легко выделяется в слове *заядлый*, он и является смыслообразующим фактором. Утверждается, что это польское заимствование, наряду с быдлом и подлецом.

"Фигушки, я плотоядная!" (хищная корова из мультфильма)))